# In activity OnDestroy is it necessary to remove event handlers for buttons and set to null for memory allocation?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Currently have the following code within an activity

```
//declaration
public Android.Widget.Button logInButton;

//assigning
logInButton = FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.loginButton);
logInButton.Click += logInButton_Click;
```

Then on my OnDestroy method doing the following for memory allocation.

```
logInButton.Click -= logInButton_Click;

logInButton = null;

GC.Collect();
```

Is what I am doing in my OnDestroy really necessary or is it over kill ?

Would just setting the button to null and calling the garbage collector achieve the same result ?

Comment: Don't think it's advised to call the garbage collector, even caling it there is no guarantee that logInbutton will be collected on that pass.

Comment: In android if you're finishing an activity, all its resources are queued for garbage collection. So, all the objects that was used by this activity will be freed during next GC cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do that. Especially not for click listeners without any static context references e.g. to another activities (which is bad in the first place). Besides that there is no guarantee that `onDestroy()` will always be called. You should not rely on that and use the other lifecycle hooks do to some un-registering for example from an observer list or similar.

In short: You don't need to do that for your case.

Comment: In addition to Murats answer, I recommend to use OnPause to detach and Onresum to attach the event handler.

Comment: Thanks @tequilaslammer,  but are you saying so it is necessary to remove the event handlers in Xamarin for the objects to be collected by the garbage collector ?